# Take a column from matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, position, selection

so I want to be able to take a column of a matrix,do wanted operation on it,then place it back in the matrix.What I thought, is that I take the matrix,transpose it,do operation on column,then transpose it again.For my matrix transposition,I have:

```
 def transpose(matrix):

     return list(map(list, zip_longest(*matrix, fillvalue=0)))
```

And then for my function to manage column, I tried:

```
def gestion_colonne(matrix):
    matrix = transpose(matrix) 
    print(matrix)  # to see if the matrix was transposed
    column = int(input('wich column to modify?'))
    alist = matrix[column-1]
    list_manage(alist) #send the column to the menu that do operation on it(ex:reverse it,sort it...)
    matrix =  list(map(list, zip_longest(*matrix, fillvalue=0))) #transpose again to row turn to initial column
```

However,the code doesnt work,it does modifiy a row,but not a column,and sometimes it doesnt do anything at all.

Comment: Considered using numpy?

Comment: Do you have example matrix? Are these sparse matrixes?

Answer (score 0):

As long as these are not sparse matrices (i.e. every row same length  as each and every col same length but len row does not need to be the same as the col length) I think you may be overthinking this.

Suppose you want `f(x)` to be x*10 for every element in col 1 of a 3x4 matrix.

Several ways to do that.

***Transpose, modify the row, transpose:***

```
# our matrix
matrix=[
         [1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9],
         [10,11,12]   
        ]
# our function
def f(x): return x*10       

# transpose 3x4 to 4x3
T=list(zip(*matrix))   
print('{}\n\ttransposed:\n{}'.format(matrix, T))

# modify row in question
T[1]=tuple(f(x) for x in T[1])

# show transposed back matrix vs original matrix
print('{}\n\t col modified:\n{}'.format(matrix, [list(row) for row in zip(*T)]))
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
    transposed:
[(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
     col modified:
[[1, 20, 3], [4, 50, 6], [7, 80, 9], [10, 110, 12]]
```

***In place list comprehension:***

OR, you can just modify the matrix in place with a list comprehension:

```
>>> matrix
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
>>> matrix=[[f(x) if i==1 else x for i, x in enumerate(sl)] for sl in matrix]
>>> matrix
[[1, 20, 3], [4, 50, 6], [7, 80, 9], [10, 110, 12]]
```

***Numpy:***

If you want to perform arithmetic on columnar data, you might consider using numpy which can do this without transposing or looping across every element:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])   
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
>>> a[:,1]*=10
>>> a
array([[  1,  20,   3],
       [  4,  50,   6],
       [  7,  80,   9],
       [ 10, 110,  12]])
```

Or, if you want to put the numpy version into the same `f(x)` type:

```
>>> a[:,1]=[f(x) for x in a[:,1]]
```

Numpy is the fastest and easiest. It does have a learning curve though.